# PowerBI requesting internal API path

Tags: asp.net, odata, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I call my API in PowerBI using the OData feed option e.g

example.com/odata/People

Which works fine. Then in fiddler I call

example.com/odata/

This returns the metadata and link fine too using mysite.com as the host for the metadata url.

However if i click on a linked table record that comes from the people data it throws a 404 saying it can't call the underlying API e.g

example.azurewebsites.net/hrm/insights/People(a8caba52-5729-4c0e-935c-a72300eea371)/Contacts

This is not using my domain, what is PowerBI calling to get this url instead of the one I provided it?